# How do I create an array of date intervals from an array of static dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

From an array:

```
["01/01/2015", "02/01/2015", "03/01/2015", "05/01/2015", "06/01/2015"];
```

to

```
[{begin_date: "01/01/2015", end_date: "03/01/2015"}, { begin_date: "05/05/2015", end_date: "06/01/2015 }];
```

Is there a library available for this type of functions?

Edit More info: I would like to convert the first array of static dates to an array of objects that represent time intervals.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a JSON string correct?

Comment: Yes. My table structure in the back end is supposedly best in the format start_date | end date.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Not a valid programming question? Would seem like a useful library though, but haven't found it on Google yet...

Comment: What is the logic behind conversion you're trying to do? I don't see the connection between the first and second array.

Comment: To convert an array of ordered dates to an collection of objects that represent date intervals instead.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to fit odd-numbered amount of data into a format that requires an even-numbered amount of data.  In the array, which strings are the start dates and which are the end dates?

Comment: So in the first array, there are just dates that were selected from a calendar. In case of just sending them like that, I want to convert them to date intervals first. This means, to check which dates are adjacent and belong together. Perhaps the example isn't very clear.

Comment: Ugh sorry, the example was wrong, I corrected it.

Comment: Ah, I see. You wouldn't need a library for that. Just split them by '/', use the `new Date(year, month, day)` and loop through them and see where there's a more than one day gap.

Comment: The example still seems wrong - your array has 5 dates and the result object has 4.

Comment: The result array have two objects, because there are two intervals. The first array is just an array of dates.

Comment: From an earlier comment: "This means, to check which dates are adjacent and belong together." - how can you determine this when you have an odd number of entries in the first array?

Comment: That doesn't matter, I just wanted to create date intervals. But I will check it out first; I thought there might have been some good libraries to handle well-known functionality for solving date-range problems. But I'll check first.

Answer (score 0):

I work with Moment objects and underscore. I ended up with the following working code:

```
        //Create arrays 
        var coll_dateIntervals = []; 
        var arr_temp = []; 
        _.each(collDates, function(moment_date, index, list){ 
            //Day difference in # of days 
            var diff = Math.abs(collDates[index].diff(collDates[index + 1], "days")); 

            //Add begin_date 
            arr_temp.push(moment_date); 
            //Check the date difference in days. 
            if(diff <= 1 && diff !== undefined){ 
                //If the difference is 1, than add the date to the temporary array 
                arr_temp.push(moment_date); 
                //If it's more than 1 day, or the last object 
            } else if (diff > 1 || diff === undefined){ 
                //Store the interval in an object 
                var obj_dateInterval = { start_date: arr_temp[0].format("DD/MM/YYYY"), end_date: arr_temp[arr_temp.length - 1].format("DD/MM/YYYY")}; 
                coll_dateIntervals.push(obj_dateInterval); 

                //Empty the array to start the new loop 
                arr_temp = []; 
            }; 
        }); 
        console.log(coll_dateIntervals); 

        //return coll_dateIntervals;
```